# unable to restrict combobox height when used in a datagrid

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript

I am using a combobox in a flex datagrid using an item renderer and things were fine till the height of combobox was equal to the rowheight. Now I have one more item renderer whose height is greater than the row height of the datagrid. The problem I am facing is that the combobox tries to fill the entire rowheight! ..I tried setting the maxheight, explicit maxheight, explicitheight in the combobox itemrenderer but nothing works. One of the solutions is to use a VBox as the itemrenderer for the comboboxcell, but its a terrible solution as its heavy and adds more complications.

Comment: I don't understand what the problem is.  Perhaps a screenshot may help here.  Perhaps showing some code.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using a combobox in a VBox ... A cellrenderer will render the complete cell...so if the cell is 20 px in height, the combobox will be 20 px in height too...So I used a Vbox and then restricted the height of the combobox (which I added as a child of VBox)